# Search And Replace A Line In Java When The String Have Many Same Other Strings

Tags: java, android

Ok you might have got idea what i am thinking

okay i will go step by step to make things clear

i have a file in android like here :- /sdcard/file.xml

now i want to search the string name which is also present as same in this file

like i have text like this in xml

this is file.xml on different device

```
<any name="class">
<index="23" />
<item name="item1" />
<item name="item2" />
<item name="item3" />
</any>
<any name="school">
<index="12" />
<item name="item2" />
<item name="item3" />
<item name="item1" />
</any>
```

this is file.xml on different device

```
<any name="class">
<index="26" />
<item name="item2" />
<item name="item1" />
<item name="item3" />
</any>
<any name="school">
<index="11" />
<item name="item1" />
<item name="item3" />
<item name="item2" />
</any>
```

i am taking

```
<any name="class">
```

to search the word as it can not be different on devices

but as you can see here the next index is different and items can be up and down as well

but actually i want to replace item2 where ever it exist in `<any name="class">`

any way i can replace this ?

Comment: What is your current solution? And please make the explanation of your question more succinct.

Comment: String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("This is test string", "blah blah blah");  i used to do this but this will not work anymore as this is text string have so many this is text strings in same name file on different devices :)

Comment: anybody have any idea ?

Comment: still i did not got any workaround yet :(

Comment: People can't help you when they can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: i have totally explained it in much better way read again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
String updatedXML = inputXML.replaceAll("<any name=\"(\\d+)\">", 
      "<myreplacement id=\"$1\">");
```

Here `(\\d+)` means "any number of digits can be here, assign them to the group#1" and `$1` means "insert group#1 contents here".

Comment: bro i updated my post im taking to make it clear <any name="01">  is the file which stays same in different devices so i am taking <any name="01"> to search the starting position and then look for item 2 replace and index between

Comment: and what about the (\\d+)  when it has strings ? sometimes it doesnot have digits then ?